# In twisted.trial how to test if a callback is not called within timeout?

Tags: twisted

I'm implementing pubsub pattern within twisted.
And wonder how to test in trial that pub only triggers proper subs, but not others.

I can test if proper subs are called:

```
def test_pubsub(self):
  d1 = defer.Deferred()
  d2 = defer.Deferred()
  self.bus.sub("/foo", lambda ev: d1.callback(ev))
  self.bus.sub("/foo/bar", lambda ev: d2.callback(ev))
  self.bus.pub("/foo/bar", {})
  return defer.gatherResults([d1, d2])
test_pubsub.timeout = 2
```

Now i want to test that

```
self.bus.sub("/foo/bar/baz", callback_will_not_be_called)
```

Upd. The only idea i came up with:

```
self.bus.sub('/foo/bar/baz', lambda ev: d4.callback(ev))
d4.addCallback(lambda e: self.fail("should not happen"))
reactor.callLater(1.9, lambda: d4.cancel())
self.assertFailure(d4, defer.CancelledError)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using the "real" reactor for this test.  The 'timeout' feature in Trial is not designed to make assertions about the behavior about your tests, but rather, to allow hung or buggy tests to exit so that the rest of the suite can continue.  Instead, follow the documented guidelines for [testing scheduling of timed calls within Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/trial.html#auto9).

Comment: Ok. 
I can use twisted.internet.task.Clock to check if something happens within timeout.
But how to check that something does not happen?

Comment: Call `clock.advance(...)`.  Then, immediately afterwards, synchronously within your test, assert that the thing has not happened.  If you don't run the reactor, but just create in-memory representations of the components under test (like the reactor's `callLater` implementation on `Clock`) then you don't need to let any actual time pass, just tell your code that time has passed with `advance`.